# Numpy: Sum clumps of rows

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, numpy

What I would like to figure out how to sum every two rows of an array. EG convert a to b in this example:

```
a=array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])

b=array([[ 4,  6,  8, 10],
       [20, 22, 24, 26]])
```

Current code looks something like this:

```
b=[]
for num in range(len(a)/2):
    b.append(a[num*2]+a[num*2+1])
```

Surely there must be a faster way. Thank you for your time.

Answer found as:

```
b=a[::2,:]+a[1::2,:]
```

Which actually helps me expand on a secondary problem of how to skip the initial two rows.

```
>>> a=np.arange(24).reshape(6,-1)
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23]])
>>> b=np.vstack((a[:2],a[2::2,:]+a[3::2,:]))
>>> b
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [20, 22, 24, 26],
       [36, 38, 40, 42]])
```

Much thanks for the help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Slicing to the rescue!  We just need to specify the stride to the slice and we're all set.

```
b = a[::2,:] + a[1::2,:]
```

demo:

```
>>> from numpy import *
>>> a=array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
...        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
...        [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
...        [12, 13, 14, 15]])
>>>
>>> a[::2,:]
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
>>>
>>> a[1::2,:]
array([[ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])
>>>
>>> a[::2,:] + a[1::2,:]
array([[ 4,  6,  8, 10],
       [20, 22, 24, 26]])
```

Comment: Your solution is much more straight-forward than mine :)

Comment: Ah this is great, and easily expandable!